# PHP to XML w/ google maps api

Tags: php, xml, database, google-maps

Hello everyone I am relatively new to php, xml and databases in general! I'm following the docs at google, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps, which show how to output places saved in a database to xml. I have a php file that reads the database and formats it to xml. I am confused with the points after that. The function to plot the markers reads an xml file, so i'm presuming instead of echoing the xml data on the php file, I export it to a xml file. If I had a big database with people adding to it would I create a new php file which runs when new places are added to add the new rows of the database to the xml file as they are been added? It seems it wouldn't be very clever to, every time the website loads, read the whole database, export to xml, then read the xml and add markers to the map.

Hope you can understand what I mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create XML file. You can apply your XML DOM to GMaps API.
Change your PHP script to return XML content-type and generated DOM.

`downloadUrl('myPHPscript.php'` <- this should return XML content type generated XML DOM.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but when I call the 'downloadurl' function in javascript it doesn't run. I put the url /*file*.php but nothing

Comment: set header `header('Content-type: application/xml');` and return generated tree.